# Omitting missing data in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data, na

I have the following dataframe:

```
DF <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3,NA), y = c(1,0, 10, NA), z=c(43,NA, 33, NA))
```

If I want to omit only `x = NA` and `z = NA`.

`complete.cases` deletes all the row contains `NA` for desired column.

Therefore, I am not sure how to only delete the last row in the dataframe `DF`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear whether you want to exclude rows where x OR z = NA or x AND z = NA. Change the boolean from and `&` to or `|` if that's the case:

```
> DF[!(is.na(DF$x) & is.na(DF$z)),]
  x  y  z
1 1  1 43
2 2  0 NA
3 3 10 33
```

Comment: Yes, that's what i want, the intersection for NA in Y and NA in X